# NOKOGIRI::XML | Delete parent where child count = 0

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, parent

All I want to do is parse the XML below and delete **Peter** and **Sam** element as they dont have any children (also can say empty) and **President** element after that as it will be empty.
This nested thing is driving me crazy!

```
<Office  id="xyz" scope="node">
  <John>
    <age>23</age>
    <ssn>230231111</ssn>
  </John>
  <Peter>
  </Peter>
  <John>
    <age>25</age>
    <ssn>222222222</ssn>
  </John>
 <President>
  <Sam>
  </Sam>
 </President>
</Office>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
doc.xpath('//*[not(*) and normalize-space(text())=""]').remove
```

- not(*) selects nodes without children
- normalize-space(text())="" selects nodes with empty text (trimmed
  whitespace)

Do it 2x to remove President too.

Comment: Or do `n = doc.xpath('//*[not(*) and normalize-space(text())=""]').remove.count` until `n` is zero.

Comment: So is your XPath, I got hung up on the whitespace issue earlier so thanks for the `normalize-space` reminder.